# Did the BBC interview a relative of Augusto Pinochet regarding the Chilean election?

Tags: media

This [verified Twitter post](https://twitter.com/marcusbarnett_/status/1472933253132734467?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1472933253132734467%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.redditmedia.com%2Fmediaembed%2Frksihp%3Fresponsive%3Dtrueis_nightmode%3Dfalse) shows a BBC "man in the street interview" of a Chilean voter who is allegedly a relative of former dictator [Augusto Pinochet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augusto_Pinochet).

[image]

I've tried to research more but the only other evidence I can find is a mention in a [Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/tv/tv-news/ghislaine-maxwell-alan-dershowitz-interview-bbc-1235068400/#!) article about their decision to interview Alan Dershowitz after the Ghislaine Maxwell verdict.

Is this a real screenshot from a BBC interview? If so, is Gonzalo a relative of the late dictator or is the name just a coincidence?

Comment: Why does this matter?  Why is this something worth being skeptical about?

Comment: @jwodder If you click the link, it tells you who Pinochet was.

Comment: I don't see how it matters whether someone is related to a dictator deposed thirty years ago.  Everyone is allowed to have relatives.

Comment: @jwodder Additionally, the subtitle says "Kast voter". Surely even you believe that when interviewing a relative of former leader about the new leader, that just might be something relevant viewers should know?

Comment: @jwodder What matters is that the interview is being presented as though Pinochet is just a random person they found in the street. If he is in fact the son of a right-wing dictator who infamously used to have leftists thrown out of helicopters, then he's not going to be the most unbiased person in the world to talk to about a democratically-elected leftist president, and the BBC (a supposedly unbiased organisation) would be doing a great disservice by obscuring his identity.

Comment: None of Augusto Pinochet's children are called Gonzalo. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luc%C3%ADa_Hiriart

Comment: @DJClayworth Sorry, I must have had a bit of a mental lapse while writing my earlier comment. The claim is that Gustavo is a *relative* of Pinochet's, not necessarily that he's his son.

Comment: How close a relative does someone have to be for this to be an issue? In your opinion? And are any of the claimants actually stating what his relation is, or are they keeping it comfortably vague? The only other claim I've found says "distant cousin", which makes this a total nothingburger.

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't think it matters to the question. If you have an answer- and "yes they did, he's he's his father's brother's nephew's cousin's former roommate", post it as an answer.

Comment: The answer is that there appears to be pretty much no evidence that they are related. Is that the answer you are looking for?

Comment: @DJClayworth If you're asking if I hoped the answer was "yes, it's his grandson" so I could join the bandwagon, does it matter? I thought I'd be responsible and verify it (didn't think I'd be attacked for doing so). That'd be a good answer in lieu of anything better. A great answer would identify Pinochet's patrilineal descendants and show that none named Gonzalo would be the appropriate age.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The footage states Gonzalo is "[a distant cousin of the former dictator](https://twitter.com/i/status/1472912759704760327).

It's unclear how distant he actually is.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have reached the point where we can ask "Is the person interviewed closely enough related to Augusto Pinochet to be significant?" and give the answer "No".

Reasons:

- ["Pinochet" is a common surname in Chile - about 4000 people have it.](https://forebears.io/surnames/pinochet) 99% of those people are not closely related to Augusto Pinochet.
- This claim is actually not being made with any frequency. I've located only two distinct claims (not counting simple repeats of a claim). [One says "They are related" without giving any details](https://twitter.com/marcusbarnett_/status/1472933253132734467) and [the other says "is a distant cousin".](https://www.reddit.com/r/GenZedong/comments/rl3n2p/bbc_but_have_you_considered_the_opinion_of/) I wouldn't count a "distant cousin" as close enough to worry about. Neither would be considered a reliable source. Hollywood reporter says "The BBC was criticized for interviewing a relative of Augusto Pinochet" without giving details of how close a relative it was.
- If there somebody who made the claim actually knew that the relationship was a close one, they would be giving us details. That hasn't happened.

Comment: Thanks. Not really worth the downvotes and attacks I got but that's my fault for not just using Quora.

Comment: One further addendum to the second reason would be: "Who is criticising the BBC for this?" Was it some random person on Twitter with three followers, or was it Ofcom?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Verified Twitter account with 18k followers. Definitely enough not to be considered some random person (otherwise the downvoters would have closed this).

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim - I was talking in general, rather than this specific case and giving examples of extremes.